# What is going on in this plot?

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

```
Plot[{ArgMax[Cos[t] Sinc[2*Pi kl (Sin[t] - 1/Sqrt[2])], t]*180/Pi, 
  45}, {kl, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

I want to know what causes this, and how to fix it in case it happens in the future.

Comment: You can investigate this, for example, by looking at `ContourPlot[Cos[t] Sinc[2 Pi kl (Sin[t] - 1/Sqrt[2])], {kl, 4, 6}, {t, -8, 8}, PlotRange -> All]`. It seems pretty nasty...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted by [kirma](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3056/kirma), this function is highly oscillatory.  However, from its form it is periodic in `t` with period `2 Pi` and has its maximum near `Pi/4` except for small `kl`.  For instance,

```
Plot[Evaluate[Cos[t] Sinc[2 Pi kl (Sin[t] - 1/Sqrt[2])] /. 
    kl -> Range[0, 2, 1/2]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Because `ArgMax` sometimes finds a local maximum instead of the global maximum, we can help it by adding a constraint that takes advantage of the fact (just shown) that the maximum lies between `0` and `Pi/4`.

```
Plot[{ArgMax[{Cos[t] Sinc[2*Pi kl (Sin[t] - 1/Sqrt[2])], 
    0 < t < Pi/2}, t]*180/Pi, 45}, {kl, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

as desired.